# How to setup Vue-axios cross-domain-origin for Laravel API?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

How can I setup a cross domain cofiguration for a Vue application ? I have a Laravel API serving on a different domain. So when I'm trying to send and API request it's not sending it to correct API destination rather it's sending to own domain (for instance, vue is serving on `devport.findosman.xyz` & I'm trying to access API at `api.devport.findosman.xyz/api/login`, but sending to `devport.findosman.xyz/login`). Note that I am using axios as following

**API.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const injectAccessToken = (config) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  if (accessToken)
    config.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  return config;
};

const config = {
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH,
};

const API = axios.create(config);

API.interceptors.request.use(injectAccessToken);

export default API;
```

**Login.vue**

```
import API from "@/api/Api";

<script>
  const res= await API.post('login')
</script>
```

What I've tried already is:

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_PORT,  
    proxy: 'api.devport.findosman.xyz/api',
  },
};
```

**env.development**

```
VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH = 'http://localhost:8000/api'
VUE_APP_DEV_PORT = 3000
```

But this not still not working. Am I missing something important in client side or It's also need some change in laravel side also?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried integrating a middleware like this in your app?:
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: yet not & that might be an issue. but here, in the picture above as you see, the request yet not reaching the API, it's hitting at the wrong url instead. So there is still some issues on the vue side. isn't it ?

Answer (score -1):

in vue.config.js, write the foreign url, and in axios, write the origin url from where you are attempting to access the foreign url. Here is an example:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_PORT, // this should be: api.devport.findosman.xyz
    proxy: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH,
  },
};
```

and when you start the request, use the origin url

```
axios.get(originUrl); // could be http://localhost or wherever from you're attempting to access that site
```

Comment: what if I read these value from .env file ?